# There's or there are

Tags: grammar

> There are over 100 new characters in the new show.
>
> There's over 100 new characters in the new show.

I've heard both for some strange reason. There are a few examples on Google books, so I thought it was strange. You should say "there are", but I saw a few examples with "there is over".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There are" is grammatically correct. The verb and the object should agree in number (both are plural).

"There's" can be a contraction of either "There is" or "There has", neither of which is grammatical in this sentence.

IMO the most likely reason for "There's over 100..." was just a mistake in spoken English. The speaker said "There's" *before* realizing that the object of the verb was plural.

FWIW There are some rarely used contractions like "when're", "which're", "what're" for "when are, "which are", "what are", etc. I suppose "there're" would fit that pattern, though it is hard to pronounce and doesn't save any space in written English.

Comment: In spoken English using "there's" as a contraction for "there are" is so common as to *almost* not be an error, in my experience. In standard written English it would never be correct.