# There was lots of different folks

Tags: idiomatic-language

Folks, I've got a question that has to do with the tendency of English natives to use *was* instead of *were* in there-constructions when *were* should grammatically be used.
So, the question is do people really use *was* instead of *were* in this case as often as they say *there's* instead of *there are* in the present (which I do know they do quite often)?

1. There was lots of different folks in our mansion.
2. There was four quinces and one long-ago-dried camomile flower, which I had once accidentally encountered in the forest, in the drawer.

Comment: An interesting wrinkle here is whether to treat a collective noun, such as “the family,” as grammatically singular or plural. Google Ngrams shows that “family was” is much more common than “family were” today, but the opposite was true in the 1800s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are)

Comment: ...also [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/) and [Using "there is" with plural nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284436/) and [The use of "there is" and "there's"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267343/) and [There's or there are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290963/) and ["There is some" or "There are some"- which is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326793/) AND OTHERS!

Comment: @Davislor: I suspect that just reflects the fact that Americans (who favour singular for ***family***) don't completely dominant C19 texts indexed by Google.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No good guess, but, I checked both the AmR and BrE corpuses. I do have the impression that collective nouns taking plural verbs is more common in Britain, and always considered an “error” in America. For example, [the BBC’s “Learning English” website](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv358.shtml) claims that both “the government is” and “the government are” are correct, but in American English, we always say “the Administration is.”

Comment: @Davislor: My perception is that Brits are more flexible than Americans when it comes to things like this. We tend to change the plurality of nouns like government, police, family according to whether the *context* suits a single entity or multiple members of a group.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To put some numbers on it, “Conservative government is” is about nine times more common in the BrE corpus than “Conservative government are,” but “Biden administration are” and “Trump administration are” do not appear in the corpus at all.

Comment: Some more numbers, from site-specific searches of *The Guardian* - ["but the family **is**"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2F+++%22but+the+family+is%22) 2630 results, ["but the family **are**"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2F+++%22but+the+family+are%22) 1640 results. Trying the same two searches on *The New York Times* returns 81 and 87 hits - but I think those values are meaningless because NYT is behind a paywall and can't be properly searched.

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *There was/were* [*lots of different folks in our mansion*].
>
> [2] *There was/were* [*four quinces and one long-ago-dried camomile flower, which I*
> *had once accidentally encountered in the forest, in the drawer*].

The number of the whole NP depends on the number of the word that is complement of the preposition "of". "Folks" and "quinces" are clearly plural so the verbs should also be plural, i.e. "were".

In informal style, however, especially in **present tense** declaratives with reduced *is*, many speakers  treat "there" as always singular: they say *There's* *lots of different folks in our mansion* instead of *There are lots of different* *folks in out mansion*.

Comment: I sometime think that in many informal British accents it is awkward to pronounce _they're_ differently from _their_ and _there_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So much so that the difference doesn't exist anymore. I have a standard British accent and it has never even occurred to me to pronounce they're differently from there or their. We understand the meaning from context.

Comment: This does indirectly give the answer to the question, but in rather a roundabout way. It would be a better answer if it made it clearer that the answer is **no**, people do not treat _there_ as inherently singular as commonly in past-tense declaratives as they do in reduced present-tense declaratives.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the plural would be considered "correct" and would be the form used in careful writing.  The singular would be a very common "mistake" in spoken English.

You do get (possibly) correct use of a singular when the sense is "a group" or "an event".  Eg.  "There was a lot of folks in the mansion". "What was happening? — There was people eating" You also see "was" with implied parallelism "There was a short cat and a big dog"

In speech you can't "edit",  and you tend to form sentences in response to questions:

> Who was in your <s>mansion</s> block of flats?
>
> There was ... lots of different people...

The speaker will tend to use "was" because the question did too.

(mansion seems to be the wrong word. It means stately home. I suspect you are using the Japanese word which sounds similar.

In carefully written English, you would not use "was".